# Tensorflow install--python can import but ipython cannot

Tags: python, ubuntu, tensorflow, ipython, anaconda

I just installed tensorflow for Ubuntu 16.04 through Anaconda3.  I can run the test tensorflow script with python and have no issues.  But when I run it with ipython, it cannot find the modules.  How can I link ipython to read the same libraries as the python ones?

Answer (score 0):

Did you notice your anaconda environment? Did you launch your ipython in the same environment as you installed tensorflow?

Comment: Yes I did.  I did a pip install ipython in the env again and now it works!